# Can't see data control after changing ADF project to use maven

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am using JDeveloper 12c and I recently changed the building tool of my ADF project to maven. My project is dependent on other projects. However, I can't see the other's projects' data controls in my project.

Apart from that, the project does recognize the dependency and it compiles.

What can possibly cause it to happen?

Answer (score 3):

#### Solution : Follow Steps and get successful

1. remove all library dependency from Project properties.
2. Add library path in Resource Palette.
3. Add Library from  Resource Palette to the project
4. clicking "Refresh ADF Library Dependencies in..." after right clicking the project

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clicking "Refresh ADF Library Dependencies in..." after right clicking the project, and restarting jdev ?

With ant, this happens very often to me. Just compiling/deploying jar doesnt cut it for some reason.

Hope it was helpful.

Comment: Hey, this option does not exists when using maven. But after talking to the oracle support, it's probably a bug.